# How to use a static library?

Tags: ros, library, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Specifically, I am trying use the RoBoIO library that comes with the RoBoard.
The library consists of two folders: Include, which has all the .h files, and Lib, which has a .a file.

Without using ROS, I can use the functions provided by library by linking it through this MAKEFILE:

```
test.exe : test.o
    gcc -o test.exe test.o -L../Lib -lRBIO -lstdc++
test.o : test.cpp
    gcc -c test.cpp -I../Include

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm test.o test.exe
```

What do I need to do if I want the library to linked when I use rosmake to compile my program??
I tried to simply include the .h file, but that didn't work. The library functions became undefined.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52078/how-to-use-a-static-library?/) by [Dumpsomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/3304/dumpsomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2013-01-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can add compile flags in your CMakeLists file.
check out here for details [Cmakelists Examples](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists/Examples)

---

Originally posted by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) with karma: 1850 on 2013-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0